# DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSet is not being called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog

so I have a weird problem.
I'm trying to create a DatePickerDialog that changes an inner variable when the date changes.
I've done the following but it's not being called.

```
     calendar = (Calendar) getArguments().getSerializable(DATE_ARGUMENT);
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                calendar.set(i, i2, i3);
            }
        },year, month, day);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently setting the DatePickerDialog's listener isn't the right thing to do.
You need to set the inner DatePicker listener, like the following:

```
  d.getDatePicker().init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                calendar.set(i, i2, i3);
            }
        });
```

This way whenever the user updates the date inside the dialog, the listener callback is fired and the inner variable date changes.